# Como atualizar uma imagem no tkinter

Tags: imagem, tkinter

Olá, gostaria de saber como faço para ter uma imagem no meu botão quando eu pressiono ele e uma outra imagem quando ele não está sendo pressionado.

Comment: O que já tentou? Tem algum código?

Comment: Eu fiz esse para testar:                                                                         
img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('sss.png'))
def teste():
    img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('ss.png'))
    tutu.configure(image=img2)
    tutu.image = img2
tutu = Button(image=img1, command=teste)
tutu.grid()                                                                                                 
Eu quero que depois de eu clickar no botão ele mude para ss.png e depois volte para a imagem inicial dele a sss.png